# Is [systems.windows.media] a useful tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

I received a suggested edit today to add the [system.windows.media](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/system.windows.media) tag to a question.  This is [the name of a namespace in the .NET framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), but it doesn't seem especially narrow, nor something which is likely to have an expert beyond somebody being experience with .NET in general.

The tag wiki has no description and only 22 questions attached to it.

**I am inclined to remove the tag entirely.**

However, I don't deal with .NET a great deal in my current programming life, so **I could easily be in error on this stance**.  A counterpoint is the [system.drawing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/system.drawing) tag which has 654 tagged questions, a brief wiki, and is fairly broad itself.

Could some developers with more experience in .NET chime in on this?

Comment: This should not be done. The tag serves an important function for categorizing questions about a group of API functions. People can be experts about an API.  Usually tags for individual classes or methods are too narrow to be useful, but tags for APIs around a specific functional area ARE useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I'd agree with you on this. The questions you should ask here are:

> Will removing the tag make the question less understandable or less discoverable?
>
> Would a question with just this tag make sense?

If either of the answers are "yes" then leave the tag. If they are both "no" then the tag can go.

With only 22 questions with the tag it's probably safe to go ahead and make the edits yourself. Just space them out over an hour or so to avoid flooding the home page (however briefly) and knocking newer questions off the page.

Comment: Looks like somebody beat me to cleaning up the tag.  Thank you for the guidance!

Comment: No, the tag is still there, you just misspelled it in your question.  ;)

Comment: While I agree with the logic for deciding whether or not to burninate, I don't think it's appropriate for this specific tag. The namespace in question contains enough classes/functionality to effectively be its own API, deserving of its own tag. Someone can be an expert in using the Windows.Media classes.

Comment: @ChrisHayes This namespace doesn't stand much on its own - "Provides types that enable integration of rich media, including drawings, text, and audio/video content in Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) applications.". It, from both the usage scenarios and the internal implementation points of view, is a part of WPF. Most if not all classes there are in the main WPF assembly(PresentationFramework.dll), and they are extensively used in more complex classes(controls and etc.). It is not as much as a separate API, but rather an integral part of a more complex library.